# Quit Button keeps generating tkMessageBox.askokcancel pop ups

Tags: tkinter

This is part of my GUI application. Everything works well. I just have question regarding pop up for `tkMessageBox.askokcancel` for my `QUIT` call
I noticed that for every click on `QUIT` button I get its respective pop up,
I want only one instance of pop up to display.

### Quit button

```
self.Quitbuttonvar = Button(self.parent, text="Quit", command = self.Quitcall)

def Quitcall(self):
   if tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really want to quit?"):
            self.destroy()
            raise SystemExit
```

I am using Python 2.5, that is required for the project that I am working on.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that would cause `Quitcall` to be called more than once when you click the button.

Comment: When I click "QUIT" button on GUI. It opens Pop Up with "OK and Cancel" option. if I don't choose an option and I click "QUIT" again it opens another pop up with "OK and Cancel" ...     I changed the above to tkMessageBox.askokcancel("Quit", "Do you really want to quit?",master=self.parent) and worked fine this time. Couldn't figure out the above , but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that the user can only click on the button and get a dialog once, you can disable the "Quit" button in the callback, and restore the state if the user cancels.

For example:

```
def Quitcall(self):
    self.Quitbuttonvar.configure(state="disabled")
    if (tkMessageBox...):
        ...
    self.Quitbuttonvar.configure(state="normal")
```

You should also give the message box an explicit parent if you're using more than one window.